# how to do checksum using jcifs

Tags: java, jcifs

If we do file copies using Java, we have a way to do a checksum to check the source file and destination file are same and are not altered during the transmission. If we use JCIFS instead of Java File Api to do file manipulations, is there any way to do the checksum of the files ?